# Where can I find a very simple jQuery/AJAX Coldfusion tutorial?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

Edit: After following a few tutorials I am stuck [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195811/how-do-you-output-a-query-from-a-cfm-page-using-jquery-ajax-with-json-format?answertab=active#tab-top)

I am new to jquery but have some experience with Coldfusion. I have been desperate for an easy tutorial that shows how jQuery/AJAX pulls a query from a ColdFusion9 CFC and displays it on the HTML calling page. I tried following this [ben_tutorial](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1515-Ask-Ben-Building-An-AJAX-jQuery-And-ColdFusion-Powered-Application.htm?&_=0.7565910615958273#comments_38884) but it is too complex for me. There is also a another [tutorial](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2011/3/3/Easy-AJAX-using-ColdFusion-jQuery-and-CFCs), but I do not want to install a plugin. Where should I be looking? I am googling "jquery ajax coldfusion"

Comment: www.bennadel.com, he has lots of good stuff on jquery, ajax and CF. He is a real pro...

Comment: coldfusion is server side, jQuery is client side, the difference is if you are making AJAX calls, your `cfcs` can easily `returntype="JSON"` etc;

Comment: go to www.coldfusionjedi.com. Search for jquery ajax. he has lot of simple examples and demos. And also have the api.jquery.com open, so you can research on the functions. Link to sample http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/12/21/ColdFusion--jQuery-example

Answer (score 3):

You didn't elaborate on what you want to update on the client side.  Forms are common, so if you have client side html form like:

```
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="text" name="date">
<input type="text" name="author">
```

You would generate and send a JSON string with coldfusion. The JSON string could look something like:

```
{"title" : "mytitle", "date" : "mydate", "author" : "myauthor"}
```

To update the data on the client side you would execute (coldfusion-page.cfm is the name of your server side ajax responder):

```
jsonOBJ = {};
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "coldfusion-page.cfm",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
     jsonOBJ = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
     for (var key in jsonOBJ) {
       $("input[name=" + key + "]").val(jsonOBJ[key]);
     }
  },
});
```

**OR**, If you just want to update a div or textarea like:

```
<div id="uniquedivname"></div>
```

you just send the html/text and replace the success function in the ajax call with:

```
  success: function(data){
     $("#uniquedivname").html(data);
  },
```

Comment: For my .cfm page I have (below)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I had a hard time with code formatting so I posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195811/how-do-you-output-a-query-from-a-cfm-page-using-jquery-ajax-with-json-format)

Comment: Looks like you already have an answer on your followup question...

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have a fair knowledge of HTML. To accomplish the sort of thing you are asking, use this snippet:

```
$.get("coldfusion-page.cfm",function(data){
    $("#displaydiv").html(data);
});
```

$.get is a shorthand method that simply retrieves the given URL. The function() part that follows it is what is run when the request to the coldfusion page completes. All it does is put the data that came back into the HTML tag with an ID of "displaydiv".

It really doesn't get simpler than this.

Answer (score 1):

Some links I found are:

- http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2011/3/3/Easy-AJAX-using-ColdFusion-jQuery-and-CFCs
- http://blog.kukiel.net/2011/09/jquery-coldfusion-and-cfdump-into-div.html
- http://tutorial43.learncf.com/
- [Return data using ColdFusion and jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822649/help-with-return-data-using-coldfusion-and-jquery-ajax)

You can almost never go wrong reading these blogs for coldfusion

- bennadel.com
- coldfusionjedi.com
- http://cflove.org/

Comment: Thanks I got the second tutorial to work, positive momentum. Now working on the third tutorial to use ajax/json. Thank you sir!